# Generate unit samples of a linear program

Tags: linear-programming, random, simplex, constraints

Given $N \in \mathbb{N}$ segments with a width of $w_i\quad i=1,\ldots,N$.

The sum of the segments have to be 1:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{N}{w_i}=1$$

In average, the width of a segment is $1/N$ but can vary around a spread $s$:

$$\frac{1-s}{N}\leq w_i\leq \frac{1+s}{N}\quad i=1,\ldots,N$$

The problem is to generate sample data $W=(w_1,\ldots,w_N)^T$ that satisfy the constraints.

The given constraints looks like a linear program (without a min/max function). I've found the article [generate-uniform-data-in-a-simplex](http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2012/10/08/generate-uniform-data-in-a-simplex.html) but this requires a unit simplex. As described in the article, a simplex is the set

$$\Delta=\left\{x|\sum^{d}_{i=1}{x_i}=1\enspace\text{and}\enspace 0\leq w_i \leq 1 \enspace\text{for}\enspace i=1,\ldots,d\right\}$$

Is there a way to map the given problem to a simplex, generate random samples of it and remap it to the original problem?

Comment: There is a trivial solution ($w_i = \frac{1}{N}$) that satisfies the constraints. Can you be more specific about what sort of 'random distribution' you desire?

Comment: Thats right, $w_i=\frac{1}{N}$ is a solution. But the constraints span a sub space of $\mathbb{R}^N$ and I like to pick randomly a point of this space. Any point that satisfy the constrained should have the same probability to be picked by the random generator.